# Django on docker container error when trying to connect to local mysql database

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

Please help me,

I have django application that run on docker container with docker-compose, but i have error when trying to connect to mysql database on my local machine.

The error message is like this : **Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket ‘/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock’**

my docker-compose.yml file is like this :

```
 version: '3'

 services:
   web:
     container_name: web
     build: .
     command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
     volumes:
       - .:/code
     ports:
       - "8000:8000"
```

and my Dockerfile is like this :

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev -y
RUN pip install pip -U
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: You should a mysql service in your Docker Compose, currently you only have a Python container for your app.

Comment: Please also show how you configure the mysql connection. The docker container can access a mysql server on the host, but not through localhost/127.0.0.1, it needs to use the hosts ip

Answer (score 0):

I have found how Django container have to access to the MySQL  database that runs on the host,

1. If you are running on Windows, make sure your network profile is in `Private mode`.
2. Create a new Mysql user like this :

   `mysql > CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';`
   `mysql > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'monty'@'localhost'WITH GRANT OPTION;`
   `mysql > CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';`
   `mysql > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'monty'@'%'  WITH GRANT OPTION;`

   replace `'monty'` with username as you want to.
   replace `'localhost'` with your host IP Address eg. `192.168.1.50`
   replace `'some_pass'` with a password as you want.
3. On Django settings.py file set Database setting like this :

   DATABASES = {

   ```
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'monitoring',  # your database name
       'USER': 'user1',  # username that you just create above
       'PASSWORD': 'root',  # user password that you just create above
       'HOST': '192.168.1.50',   #your host IP Address where your mysql database run
       'PORT': '3306',
   }}
   ```
4. Replace the `bind-address = "127.0.0.1"` on my.cnf file to `bind-address = "0.0.0.0"`

This method is works for me and I hope this can work to all.